# a difficult question about integration proof

Tags: calculus, integration

\begin{align*}
\text { If } \quad( continuous ) fuction \quad F(t)=\iint_{[0, t]^{2}} f(x y) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{~d} y . \text {please prove: }\\
\text { (1) } F^{\prime}(t)=\frac{2}{t}\left(F(t)+\iint_{\mid 0, t]^{2}} x y f^{\prime}(x y) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{~d} y\right)
(2) F^{\prime}(t)=\frac{2}{t} \int_{0}^{t^{2}} f(s) \mathrm{d} s.
\end{align*}

I tried to use the integration of f(x) but i can't get the exprssion of F(t)
and i don't know if there's any way to go
so anyone could solve this, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! PLease update your question with what you have tried and where you are getting stuck to make it easier to guide you properly. Knwoing the context in which you saw the problem would be also very helpful. Thanks!\

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), we'll enforce $u=x/t,v=y/t$ to rid the dependence of the parameter $t$ on the domain of integration: $$F(t)=\iint_{[0,1]^2}t^2f(t^2uv)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$ Since $$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\Big(t^2f(t^2uv)\Big)=2t^3uvf'(t^2uv)+2tf(t^2uv)$$ We get with Leibniz's rule that $$F'(t)=\iint_{[0,1]^2}2t^3uvf'(t^2uv)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v+\iint_{[0,1]^2}2tf(t^2uv)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$ Applying the change of variable $p=tu,q=tv$ on *both* integrals brings us back to our original domain of integration: $$F'(t)=\frac{2}{t}\Bigg[\iint _{[0,t]^2}pqf'(pq)\mathrm{d}p\mathrm{d}q+\iint_{[0,t]^2}f(pq)\mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}q\Bigg]$$ Which is equivalent to saying $$F'(t)=\frac{2}{t}\Bigg[F(t)+\iint _{[0,t]^2}xyf'(xy)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\Bigg]$$ For (2) set $\alpha(t)=\int_0^tf(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$. Use the substitution $u=xy$ to see that $$\int_0^tf(xy)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^{ty}f(u)\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\alpha(ty)}{y}$$ It follows that $$F(t)=\int_0^t\frac{\alpha(ty)}{y}\mathrm{d}y$$ Enforce another substitution $u=ty$ to get $$F(t)=\int_0^{t^2}\frac{\alpha(u)}{u/t}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{t}=\int_0^{t^2}\frac{\alpha(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u$$ Finally, $$F'(t)=\frac{\alpha(t^2)}{t^2}\cdot 2t=\frac{2}{t}\alpha(t^2)=\frac{2}{t}\int_0^{t^2}f(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

Comment: thanks for your patience！

Comment: @jiajie no problem